# Is it acceptable to have an outside class manage a factory that returns a singleton?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, singleton, factory-pattern

I have a need where I want a class of mine to return a single instance to be shared so I was going to use a Factory that returns a singleton. My obvious approach was to place this Factory directly on the class in question as a `static` method (i.e. `.Create()) and be done with it.

The issue I'm having is my constructor on this class is relying on DI and several dependencies need to be injected. This class resides in my `Domain Layer` and cannot instantiate new instances of the repository classes representing the interfaces that need to be injected. I'm using the Repository Pattern as well, the the repository layer has access to the domain model layer, but obviously my domain model does not have access to the repository (circular reference). Bottom line: I cannot instantiate those concrete repository types representing the dependencies to be injected in the factory.

The only solution I can think of is to move the Factory up a layer, since this need to have a single instance is not driven by the class itself, but rather because of an implementation detail. Why should my class care; it does not care how it gets instantiated.

The thing is, I don't know if it's proper to have a factory managing the singleton returned of this class type, *outside* of the original class? Here is what I want to do (code is *greatly* simplified to just focus on the question:

**Layer 1: (has reference to repository and can 'new' up instances to inject into `MyClass`**

```
public MyClass Create()

    {
       if myClass = null
           myclass = new MyClass(new Repository1(), new Repository2());
       else
           return myclass;
    }
```

**Layer 2:**

```
public class MyClass
{

   public MyClass(IRepository1 repository1, IRepository2 repository2)
   {

   }

}
```

Comment: Couldn't your DI IoC container manage the singleton instance?  In the title you ask a very good question--it seems awkward in the traditional factory and singleton pattern to have this managed externally, not least of which is "how do you ensure that it's truly a singleton if it may be instantiated multiple places?" With an IoC container, however, you should be able to manage injecting the dependencies and creating just one instance (in Unity it's called "ContainerControlledLifetimeManager", for instance).

Comment: Right now I had not implemented an IoC container yet and hence the manual instantiations (this is in a Windows Service and I'm spoiled with DI resolver in MVC and WebAPI). I have used Unity and planned on adding it. So you say this will solve this issue using `ContainerControlledLifetimeManager`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider moving the whole MyClass class in the upper layer ?
Since you didn't explain what this class do, it might be a stupid answer but as it seems the class depends on repositories, I guess it is doing some sort of business logic, therefore it should not be in data layer.
That would allow you to implement the singleton directly inside the class like you would usually do.